# How can I retrieve a document reference field from a Firestore database document?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I'm using [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore) in a Xamarin.Forms project.

I'm trying to retrieve a reference field from a document in my Firestore database.

```
public class Fields
    {
        public IEnumerable<char> field1 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<char> field2 { get; set; }
       
        public IEnumerable<IDocumentReference> field3 { get; set; }
    }

var firstField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field1.ToString();
var secondField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field2.ToString();
var thirdField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field3;
```

`field1` and `field2` are of type `string`, but if I declare `IEnumerable<string>` the code doesn't work. Using `char` instead fixes the issue.

What type should I use for `field3` though, which is of type `reference`? I have tried many different types without success.

Comment: If they are all single value properties, why are you using `IEnumerable` at all?  Why not just use `string` and `IDocumentReference`?

Comment: How is the field defined in the database?  The c# class has to match the database field.

Comment: @Jason
Yeah... That fixed it for the IDocumentReference. I just had copied the class from another part of the project where `IEnumerable` was used and I unconsciously used it here too...
The IEnumerable<char> worked for the string, but not for the reference.

Comment: @jdweng
It is of type `reference` in the Firestore document. The equivalent for the plugin is IDocumentReference.
Anyway, Jason's suggestion fixed the issue.

Comment: use `string` instead of `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: I already did. `IEnumerable<char>` worked just fine for the fields of type `string` though. The problem was with the `reference`.
Anyway, I guess `IEnumerable` added to the complexity of the code for no reason, as all the fields are of single value.

Comment: Have you tried `var thirdField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field3.FirstOrDefault();` assuming you have using `using Plugin.CloudFirestore;` statement ?

Comment: @RohitKharche
No, because the problem was with this line: `public IEnumerable<IDocumentReference> field3 { get; set; }`. When I included it in the class I couldn't even retrieve `field1` and `field2` which worked fine without the aforementioned line. Anyway, I removed `IEnumerable` as there was no reason for its use and everything works great now!

Comment: @Costas As removing `IEnumerable` solved your issue post as an answer so other community members will also get the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked (based on [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason)'s suggestion):

```
public class Fields
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }

        public string field2 { get; set; }
       
        public IDocumentReference field3 { get; set; }
    }

var firstField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field1;
var secondField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field2;
var thirdField = doc.ToObject<Fields>().field3;
```